# Lightning button to redirect to record detail page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, javascript-controller, navigation

I am very new to lightning and have a basic issue with creating a button.
My requirement is that when i click on 'check my budget' button it should redirect me to the corresponding budget record of that expense.

Budget-Master object; Expense-detail object

```
<aura:component controller="budgetlightningcntrl">

<aura:attribute name="expense" type="Expenses__c[]"/>

   <aura:registerEvent name="navEvt" type="force:navigateToSObject"/>
      <aura:handler event="force:navigateToSObject" action="{!c.navigate}"/>

            <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
               <table class="slds-p-around_x-small slds-text-body_small slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout " >
                   <thead>
                       <tr>                        
                           <th scope="col" colspan="3" class="slds-truncate slds-text-align--center slds-text-align--center 
                                                       slds-text-align_right slds-text-heading_medium">My Budget and Expenses</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate ">My Budget</div></th>
                            <th scope="col" ><div class=" slds-text-align--center">Expenses ID</div></th>
                            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate  slds-text-align--right">Amount</div></th>
                            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate  slds-text-align--right">Status</div></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.expense}" var="e">
                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" >
                        <td><lightning:button variant="brand" label="check budget" onclick="{!c.navigate}" />                       
                        </td>
                        <td scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate slds-text-align--right" >
                            <a target="_blank" href="{!'/'+e.Id}">{!e.Name}</a>                                 
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        <td scope="row">
                             <div class="slds-truncate slds-text-align--right"><ui:outputNumber value="{!e.Amount__c}"/></div>
                        </td>
                        <td scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate slds-text-align--right"><ui:outputText value="{!e.Status__c}" /></div>                            
                        </td>
                        </tr>            
                         </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**Budgetdisplaycontroller.js**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

// Create the action
var action = component.get("c.getexpense");

// Add callback behavior for when response is received
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.expense", response.getReturnValue());
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
    }
});

// Send action off to be executed
$A.enqueueAction(action);
},

navigate:function(component){

var idx= event.currentTarget.id;
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
"recordId": idx,
"slideDevName": "detail"

 });
  navEvt.fire(); 
}   

 })
```

**budgetlightningcntrl.apxc**

```
  public class budgetlightningcntrl 

  {    
@AuraEnabled
public static list<Expenses__c> getexpense(){

    return[SELECT Id, Name, Name__c, Reason__c, Amount__c, Date_of_Expense__c, Status__c, 
           Mode_of_Travel__c, Category__c, Budget__c, Budget__r.Name,
           Expense_owner__c, From_Date__c, To_Date__c, isclosed__c, 
           Budget_detail__c, Reimbursed__c FROM Expenses__c];
 }}
```

Comment: change var exp  = component.get("v.expense").budget__r.id; to var exp  = component.get("v.expense").budget__c; and see if it works.

Comment: no it didnt work i got this error  This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:Budgetdisplay$controller$navigate [Maximum call stack size exceeded]
Failing descriptor: {c:Budgetdisplay$controller$navigate}

Comment: are you able to get the "var exp  = component.get("v.expense").budget__r.id;" , since you are iterating the expense value  try to get it from event.currentTarget.

Comment: This is how i have changed the navigate method now using event.curretn target but i am getting the error:                                                              "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed:[Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]

Comment: navigate: function(component, event, helper) {
  var idx = event.currentTarget.id;
  var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "idx"
        });
    navEvt.fire();

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following line in my lightning component code worked!!

```
    <aura:handler event="force:navigateToSObject" action="{!c.navigate}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem boils down to this line:

```
var exp  = component.get("v.expense").budget__r.id;
```

First of all remember Apex is case insensitive, but when you access it in you JS controller as above, you need to think case *sensitive*. So, without trying it, I'd be willing to guess that `exp` returns as `undefined` if you debugged this as there would be no `id` attribute, but rather an `Id` attribute. Likewise probably for `Budget__r` So first try:

```
var exp  = component.get("v.expense").Budget__r.Id;
```

Second thing I'd look at is that you do not explicitly query the `Id` field in your Apex query. Sure, Apex shouldn't care, but if the above doesn't help, you might do some debugging to verify you're getting any `Id` field at all in the `budget__r` object. Or alternatively, you could just use the `Budget__c` field, which should resolve to the same as `Budget__r.Id`.

Comment: I tried as u said and i am getting the following error:                                                This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:Budgetdisplay$controller$navigate [Maximum call stack size exceeded]
Failing descriptor: {c:Budgetdisplay$controller$navigate}